# How do I change the css with JQuery

Tags: jquery

`data-record-key` is added to all of my table rows. The value of this attribute increments. When a user adds a row, that row is dynamically added with ajax. I want to change the color of that row but can't figure out how to do that.

This is what that attribute looks like:

```
data-record-key="31"
```

---

```
$('#test').find('.data-record-key').val('31')
 .css("cssText", "background-color:#"+ data.record.myColor +" !important;");
```

Comment: is `data-record-key` a class?

Comment: You should be able to select that attribute like this: `$('tr[data-record-key="31"]')`

Comment: FYI, `.val()` is for getting and setting the value of an input element, it's not a selector.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you. I'm still new to JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [**attribute equals selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and apply the style,

```
$('tr[data-record-key=31]').css('backgroundColor', '#' + data.record.myColor); //no need !important
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute selector:

```
$("#test").find('[data-record-key=31]').css("cssText", "background-color:#"+ data.record.myColor +" !important;");
```